# Problem with custom shipping module

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-methods, magento-1.6

When upgrading from 1.6-1.9 our shipping module just seems to come up with problem after problem, assuming its outdated XML, was just wondering if anyone can see any issues with the config xml we have as when playing about with everything to do with the shipping module this seems to be the only thing that changing doesn't affect anything.

Just to be clear the problem we are having it, the products used to be put into a matrix (defined in config) now it just has the default handling fee as the total cost of shipping and not adding the relevant price matrix, anyway heres the config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Excellence_Ship>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Excellence_Ship>
    </modules>

    <default>
        <carriers>
            <excellence>
                <active>1</active>
                <model>ship/carrier_excellence</model>
                <title>Carrier Title</title>
                <name>Method Name</name>
                <price>5.00</price>
                <dgn_fee>3.95</dgn_fee>
                <sml_box_fee>5.50</sml_box_fee>
                <med_box_fee>7.95</med_box_fee>
                <lrg_box_fee>10.50</lrg_box_fee>
                <nonhazone>TNT</nonhazone>
                <nonhaztwo>Airsure</nonhaztwo>
                <hazone>TNT</hazone>
                <haztwo>Airsea Worldwide</haztwo>
                <lastchoice>International Signed For</lastchoice>
                <specificerrmsg>This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us.</specificerrmsg>
            </excellence>
        </carriers>
    </default>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <ship>
                <class>Excellence_Ship_Block</class>
            </ship>
            <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <cart_shipping>Excellence_Ship_Block_Cart_Shipping</cart_shipping>
                </rewrite>
            </checkout>         
        </blocks>
        <models>
        <ship>
            <class>Excellence_Ship_Model</class>
        </ship>       
        </models>
        <helpers>
        <ship>
                <class>Excellence_Ship_Helper</class>
        </ship>       
        </helpers>
    </global>

    <adminhtml>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <my_boxes>
                                            <title>Configure Boxes</title>
                                        </myboxes>
                                        <dummy_products>
                                            <title>Configure Dummy Products</title>
                                        </dummy_products>
                                        <tnt_stuff>
                                            <title>Configure TNT Tables</title>
                                        </tnt_stuff>
                                        <airsure_stuff>
                                            <title>Configure Airsure Tables</title>
                                        </airsure_stuff>
                                        <airsea_stuff>
                                            <title>Configure AirSea Tables</title>
                                        </airsea_stuff>
                                        <isf_stuff>
                                            <title>Configure ISF Tables</title>
                                        </isf_stuff>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </adminhtml>

</config>
```

Carrier:

```
<?php
class Excellence_Ship_Model_Carrier_Excellence extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface {
    protected $_code = 'excellence';

    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
    {
        if (!Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/active')) {
            return false;
        }

        $handling = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/handling');
        $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
        $show = true;
        if($show){ // This if condition is just to demonstrate how to return success and error in shipping methods

            $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
            $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
            $method->setMethod($this->_code);
            $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
            $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
            $method->setPrice($this->getConfigData('price'));
            $method->setCost($this->getConfigData('price'));
            $result->append($method);

        }else{
            $error = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_error');
            $error->setCarrier($this->_code);
            $error->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
            $error->setErrorMessage($this->getConfigData('specificerrmsg'));
            $result->append($error);
        }
        return $result;
    }
    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        return array('excellence'=>$this->getConfigData('name'));
    }
}
```

### LAST THING

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <myconfig translate="label" module="ship">
            <label>My Shipping Config</label>
            <sort_order>99999</sort_order>
        </myconfig>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <my_boxes translate="label" module="ship">
            <label>Boxes</label>
            <tab>myconfig</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <non_hazardous translate="label">
                    <label>Non-Hazardous Boxes</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <my2_dim translate="label">
                            <label>My 2 Dimensions</label>
                            <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>300</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                            <comment>Dimensions of My 2 box. L W H (one per line)</comment>
                        </my2_dim>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what problems you are experiencing exactly? Also to see changes in the XML directly, you need to disable the Magento cache

Comment: Don't have magento cache enabled and as explained; literally copy pasting from the question above `the products used to be put into a matrix (defined in config) now it just has the default handling fee as the total cost of shipping and not adding the relevant price matrix`

Comment: Ok. Can you elaborate the issues? Without the actual issue explained, it's impossible to solve the problem. The XML looks OK at first glance.

Comment: I don't know how to word it differently than I already have sorry.

Comment: Like it has a handling fee and its meant to add cost based on the config in my admin, but its not adding the cost just the default "£5" handling fee i have set

Comment: Can you post the Carrier model php file? It's located in Yournamespace/Yourmodule/Model/Carrier/Carriername.php

Comment: in updated, just confused why it works on our old site and not new one

Comment: I added an answer. It seems you carrier php file doesn't use any config fields except for the price field. Maybe you're using an old version of the custom module?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the carrier model only uses the 'price' field, as you can see in the following two lines:

```
        $method->setPrice($this->getConfigData('price'));
        $method->setCost($this->getConfigData('price'));
```

It retrieves the config data field 'price', but it doesn't use the other fields like `dgn_fee`, `sml_box_fee` etc.

Maybe you're using an older unfinished version of the extension?

Comment: I did think that was odd but it works fine on the 1.6 thats whats so weird, was thinking it was possibly something I've missed on product configuration

Comment: Have you got an idea how I'd work a solution for this to read the custom config in my admin, it works on price tables

Comment: Did you upgrade the 1.6 Magento install, or did you start over with a fresh install?

Comment: It's definitely the correct extension I'm using I've disabled others to check, am confused how it gets the prices on the old site, its not in the cache etc I've checked.

Comment: You can retrieve config fields using `$this->getConfigData('fieldname');`

Comment: Maybe there are other php files in the Carrier folder? It's possible that there's another model file

Comment: ahhh found theres a mage re-write in my modules folder lol

Comment: but not sure why its not using the re-writes in `app/code/local/Mage` any idea?

Comment: Not sure about that. If the rewritten model has a 'include_once' on top, you might want to check the file path there.

Comment: could you help me with one more thing think ive almost fixed it

Comment: see LAST THING in original post, this is first part of my system.xml for the shipping module, how would I access the value for `my2_dim` because doing `getConfigData->('my2_dim')` isn't returning anything but when I get other data from main config.xml it does :(

Comment: In that case you should use: `Mage::getStoreConfig('my_boxes/non_hazardous/my2_dim')`